# Как проложить цепочку действий в телеграм боте на JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Перешел на разработку телеграм ботов с библиотеки pyTelegramBotApi
Там был чудесный метод - bot register next step handler
Который позволял получать смс и переводить дальше на мою личную функцию обработчик. Данный инструмент позволял прокладывать целую цепочку в общении с клиентом. Ибо каждый его ответ, я последовательно мог обрабатывать и делать ветвления. Сейчас перешел на JS, за основу взял - node-telegram-bot-api, прочитал документацию от корки до корки и не нашел аналогичного инструмента. Возможно я упустил, возможно здесь это реализовывается по другому. Буду рад любой помощи.

Пример задачи где нужен этот инструмент:

```
bot: Enter age
client: 17
bot: 'name', Access closed


bot: Enter age
client: 21
bot: 'name', access is open. Enter city
client: London
bot: 'name',you have successfully submitted an application
```

Comment: Глянь [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432799/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-node-js/1432946#1432946)

Comment: Немного не то, мне нужно проложить цепочку. С запоминанием предыдущих смс от клиента.

Comment: Так а проблема-то в чём? Создай объект для юзера храни в нём всё что нужно..